# Match string beginning with ([*>@]|--) ending with one of these

Tags: regex, groovy

I do have a String like `*Task @Context >Delegation --Date` and I'd like to extract the strings between the separators `*@>` and `--`.
`*Task @Context >Delegation --Date` should yield the four strings `Task`, `Context`, `Delegation` and `Date` and `*Task 9-5 @Co-ntext >Dele-gation --Date 12-5` `Task 9-5`, `Co-ntext`, `Dele-gation` and `Date 12-5`.

```
matches = "*Task @Context >Delegation --Date" =~ /([\*@>]|--)([^\*@>\-]*)/

for (match in matches) {
    println "$match"
}
```

Works well, if the strings don't contain a `-`, but each could contain one (or more) of them. E.g.

```
matches = "*Task 9-5 @Co-ntext >Dele-gation --Date 12-5" =~ /([\*@>]|--)([^\*@>\-]*)/

for (match in matches) {
    println "$match"
}
```

So, I tried negative lookahead

```
matches = "*Task 9-5 @Co-ntext >Delegation A-Town --Date 12-5" =~ /([\*@>]|--)([^\*@>]*(?!--))/

for (match in matches) {
    println "$match"
}
```

But that doesn't work. I tried countless more combinations but I can't figure out how to deal with the two `-` as deliminators.

Output of the three approaches:

```
First
[*Task , *, Task ]
[@Context , @, Context ]
[>Delegation , >, Delegation ]
[--Date, --, Date]
// is ok

Second
[*Task 9, *, Task 9]
[@Co, @, Co]
[>Dele, >, Dele]
[--Date 12, --, Date 12]
// problems with -

Third
[*Task 9-5 , *, Task 9-5 ]
[@Co-ntext , @, Co-ntext ]
[>Dele-gation --Date 12-5, >, Dele-gation --Date 12-5]
// problems with -
```

Comment: can you put sample data and your expected output?

Comment: It's unclear what resulting strings you are expecting.  You said the first example works; what are you getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement Negative Lookahead here.

```
def s = "*Task 9-5 @Co-ntext >Delegation A-Town --Date 12-5" 
def m = s =~ /([@>*]|--)((?:(?![*@>]|--).)*)/
(0..<m.count).each { print m[it][2].trim() + '\n' }
```

**Output**

```
Task 9-5
Co-ntext
Delegation A-Town
Date 12-5
```

Comment: Why do I have to put the Negative Lookahead before the asterisk?

Comment: So, this regex checks if the strings starts with `([*@>]|--)`, then immediately that neither of `([*@>]|--)` follows, takes any next character checks it and so on? I don't get why I do the Negative Lookahead check before any character allthough any character comes before the characters to check for with the Negative Lookahead, like `.*(?![*@>]|--)` (which is more like you "would speak it out".